# Insert a table into a middle of word processing document (Open XML SDK)

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I have a template Word document which i fill details into with openXML SDK 2.0 (using c#).
I also need to insert a table into file, and i found [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850841.aspx) on MSDN.
But - the example is appending the table to the end of the document, and I want it to be somewhere in the middle.
I may need to replace this line:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
```

with something else. (The full code is in the link above).

Please help me.. I found nothing yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this may be to use `Content Controls` as placeholders to insert the table into them from code.

```
var myContentControl = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>()
    .Where(e => e.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault().Val == "myTablePlaceholder").FirstOrDefault();

SdtContentBlock sdtContentBlock1 = new SdtContentBlock();
sdtContentBlock1.Append(table); // Your table
myContentControl.Append(sdtContentBlock1);
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I found the openXML SDK productivity tool, which reflect the doc code, and I discovered the wonders of the .docx, than, I used the InsertAfter(element) function.